# Separate multiple lemon sprouts planted in a single container

Tags: seeds, seedlings, transplanting, lemons

I recently germinated and planted lemon seeds. So far they have sprouted and are healthy. My concern is, I planted about 2-3 seeds per container, and now I have about 2 sprouts in each container. When I need to transplant them, do I need to separate the sprouts and plant them individually? Or can I leave them together? Will it be two trees in one pot eventually? Or turn to one tree?

Answer (score 1):

They need to be potted separately, if you mean you planted citrus lemon tree seeds. You can move them into small, separate pots as soon as each seedling has two sets of true leaves (the first leaves are cotyledons, and don't count as true leaves).

You don't say where you got the seeds from - if they are just seeds from a lemon fruit you had, the resulting tree and its fruits will likely be different from the original lemon you bought.

Comment: I took the seeds from an organic lemon I bought. I'm not too concerned if the lemon tree produces lemons differently from the original lemon I bought. This is more for fun... I put 2-3 sprouted seeds into 1 small cup each. Each cup then had 2 sprouts or seedlings that took off. I then transferred each cup with 2 seedlings in it to a larger pot. I think this is where I made a mistake. So I guess I was suppose to separate each "seed" once it sprouted with (true leaves) into its own pot. What will happen if I let them grow together in one pot?

Comment: You'll have two trees fighting with each other for root room and nutrients if you leave them in the same pot, which won't make for great plants. But maybe you don't need so many anyway, in which case, just pull out one of the seedlings from each pot, leaving whichever one is strongest looking.